# After the initial setup, I need help figuring out setting up using different classes based on incoming url

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

So far, I have set up mod_wsgi on Ubuntu server.
Then, I got the famous hello world example working.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

So when the request comes at http:///
I get a page saying "Hello World!"
But I am stuck here and trying to figure out the next step.
Now, what I would like to do is for example, when 
the request comes for

```
http://<ipaddress>/
http://<ipaddress>/create
http://<ipaddress>/index
```

I would like to let other classes answer depending on this request.

Just like in GAE, in main.py you can have something like

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication[  
('/', Top),  
('/create',Create),  
('/index', Index), ]
```

Can someone guide me so that I can implement something like this?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Does anyone have eer implemented wsgi?
Should I just look into other frameworks source code?

Comment: You should be using a framework like Flask or Django for this, not trying to write WSGI directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that but I just wanted to really understand the basics. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hang on, are you asking how to structure a URL dispatch system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Does anyone have eer implemented wsgi? Should I just look into other frameworks source code?*

In broad terms you need to check the environment that's been passed to you and process the URL related elements through a URL dispatch system of your creation.

Or you use an existing framework.

For a couple of purposes, I've considered writing WSGI directly, but so far for convenience's sake I've always used a framework.